# Facebook Connect - Add events to an Events Page (not profile)

Tags: facebook

I have created Facebook pages with an events tab.  I am currently trying to add events to this events page via the Facebook connect API but can't work out how do it.

I can add events to my profile no problem.

Can anyone tell me how to add events to a page, is it possible?

Alternatively is there a way I can add an event to my profile and have my page automatically pick up this event (I can't see anything in the settings for this?).

Any help very much appreaciated!

Thanks

C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current API doesn't support this as far as I can see.

There is an API function which is in beta at the moment (but doesn't seem to be working as 
yet) which according to the documentation is designed to publish a post into the stream on the wall of a user, group, page or event, so this should provide the functionality needed.